# mysql check for records who have not posted since a while

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table where i am trying to locate the users who are still idle and have not done any work since the last post they did, my table structure is below code

need to account for users who have gone the longest without a post invite

i tried using the date functionality but could not figure out how longest and what date
functions are needed to take this account.

but the catch is there are bunch of date fields and every column gets updated at some point, so i want to compare that the user has not been active or doing anything in last 60 dates considering all date fields

here is my code of mysql

```
SELECT 
    tblcontact_desc.ContactID,
    COUNT(tblpost.PostID) AS NoPosts,
    tblpost.PostStatus_UpdatedDateTime,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT PostStatus_UpdatedDateTime FROM tblpost ORDER BY PostStatus_UpdatedDateTime DESC limit 1))
  FROM
    tblpost
    INNER JOIN tblcontact_desc ON (tblpost.ContactdescID = tblcontact_desc.ContactdescID) 
        GROUP BY 
    tblcontact_desc.ContactID
  ORDER BY NoPosts  DESC
```

but that seems to be bringing wrong results and showing nouser

Comment: Pretend we know nothing about your environment.  Give us example data, tables and expected results.  A minimally complete verifiable example: also what you've tried and thought through,  What you have here is a problem statement without supporting details we need to help.

Comment: Maybe you should add into for the datatypes of the shown column. (That's part of the structure of the table!)   Because, considering all date fields is hard when we do not know which field ia a date.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think it should work
ill just help you with the logic

if you are checking from the column PostDate, And suppose table name is PostTbl

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT PostDate FROM PostTbl ORDER BY PostDate DESC limit 1));
```

If DATEDIFF is more than 60, you got your user,